# IoT Rules SELECT Property with name "0"

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-events

Really struggling with selecting values in IoT Rules.

My input looks like this, and I have no control over the data coming in:

```
"data": {
        "antennas": {
            "1": "disconnected",
            "2": "connected",
            "3": "disconnected",
            "4": "connected"
        }
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is the select statement transform the above into:

```
{
  antenna_1: "disconnected",
  antenna_2: "connected",
  antenna_3: "disconnected",
  antenna_4: "connected"
}
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT data.antennas.1 as antenna_1 FROM ...

SELECT [data.antennas.1] as antenna_1 FROM ...

SELECT data.antennas[1] as antenna_1 FROM ...

SELECT data.antennas.[1] as antenna_1 FROM ...

SELECT data.antennas['1'] as antenna_1 FROM ...

SELECT `data.antennas.1` as antenna_1 FROM ...
```

But nothing seems to work... :'-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working IoT SQL statement using [get function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-get) (tested using SQL version `2026-03-23`):

```
SELECT 
get(get(get(*,"data"),"antennas"),"1") as antenna_1,
get(get(get(*,"data"),"antennas"),"2") as antenna_2,
get(get(get(*,"data"),"antennas"),"3") as antenna_3,
get(get(get(*,"data"),"antennas"),"4") as antenna_4

FROM 'your/topic'
```

Comment: Amazing thank you!  Where does it say to use * in the documentation?  I must have missed that!

Comment: it doesn't, just try, test and see :)

Comment: Thats really annoying...normally aws documentation is pretty good, at least compared to google...anyway, thanks for this!